# SwitchCell how can I set on/off programmatically on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a simple Xamarin Forms app. And in my XAML page I have two SwitchCell, I want to set ON or OFF depends from my database. I mean, I'd like to set my Facebook SwitchCell ON from my code behind. But I don't know how can I do it.

Page XAML:

```
<TableView Intent="Form" x:Name="SwiCell" RowHeight="50">
<TableRoot>
    <TableSection Title="Social Network">
        <SwitchCell  Text="Facebook"/>
        <SwitchCell Text="Twitter"/>
    </TableSection>      
</TableRoot>
```

Page .CS

```
public partial class MySetup : ContentPage
{
    public MySetup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //HERE I WANT TO SET MY SwitchCell  ON or OFF
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an x:Name to each SwitchCell:

```
<TableView Intent="Form" x:Name="SwiCell" RowHeight="50">
<TableRoot>
    <TableSection Title="Social Network">
        <SwitchCell x:Name="FacebookSwitch" Text="Facebook"/>
        <SwitchCell x:Name="TwitterSwitch" Text="Twitter"/>
    </TableSection>      
</TableRoot>
```

Then in the C#, you can reference the cells and set the On property as appropriate from the database:

```
public partial class MySetup : ContentPage
{
    public MySetup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FacebookSwitch.On = <if Facebook is on>;
        TwitterSwitch.On = <if Twitter is on>;
    }
}
```